# jQuery validation plugin - addMethod either/or validation

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a new requirement for a validation, that I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to accomplish.

I have a field that is either an email address or username.

The requirement has asked that if a user enters an email the email validation (built in method) will run, otherwise the validation will be letters with basic punctuation.

So my thoughts are - if an @ is entered, run the email validation - otherwise run the letters with basic punctuation - but I'm looking for input on possible other approaches.

Also, how would you code a two part validation if/else in this scenario?

Comment: Yeap, checking for `@` is valid since it's required in an email address (as long as it's not allowed in the user name).

Comment: @Qtax - yeah, the @ is not allowed in the username - so I'm assuming I'll need to do a funcCall, check for the @ and run each validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#frm").validate({
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    usernameemail: true,
                    maxlength: 100
                }
            }
   });

   $.validator.addMethod("usernameemail", function(value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element
            return true;
        valid = true;

        if (value.indexOf("@") > 0) {
            valid = valid && $.validator.methods.email.call(this, value, element);
        } else {
            valid = valid && $.validator.methods.username.call(this, value, element);
        }
        return valid;
    }, 'Please provide a valid username or email');

    $.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
```

You need to change the username regex to what you need, hope this helps